# Питон. Работа с текстом, частотный анализ, форматирование строк

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, list, форматирование, словарь

передо мной стоит задача :

> Создать txt-файл, вставить туда любую англоязычную статью из
>   Википедии.          Реализовать одну функцию, которая выполняет
>   следующие операции:                    прочитать файл построчно;
>   непустые строки добавить в список;
>
> - удалить из каждой строки все цифры, знаки препинания, скобки, кавычки и т.д.    (остаются латинские буквы и пробелы);
>
>   - объединить все строки из списка в одну, используя метод join и пробел,           как разделитель;
>   - создать словарь вида {"слово": количество, "слово": количество, … } для          подсчета количества разных слов,
>       где ключом будет уникальное слово, а значением - количество;
>   - вывести в порядке убывания 10 наиболее популярных слов, используя метод format   (вывод примерно следующего вида:  " 1 place --- sun ---
>       15 times \n....);
> - заменить все эти слова в строке на слово "PYTHON";
> - создать новый txt-файл;
> - записать строку в файл, разбивая на строки, при этом на каждой строке записывать не более 100 символов и не делить слова.

(c учетом последнего комментария)основную ее часть, а именно считывание, формирование словаря и форматирование строки я выполнил следующим образом:

```
import re

f = open('wiki_text.txt','r')
text = str(f.readlines())
#print("%s\n" % text)

words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{2,}',text) #Регулярка для слов от двух букв
#print("%s\n" % words)

stats = {}
for w in words:
    stats[w] = stats.get(w,0) + 1

print(stats)
w_ranks = sorted(stats.items(), key = lambda x : x[1],\
      reverse=True) [0:10]
print(w_ranks)
_wrex = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+',str(w_ranks))
_drex = re.findall('[0-9]+',str(w_ranks))
pl = [p for p in range(1,11)]
for j in range(len(_wrex)):
    places = '{} place,{} - {} times'.format(pl[j],_wrex[j],_drex[j])
    print(places)
```

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: возможно ли проще организовать ранжирование слов по частоте, т.е при форматировании строки обойтись без вспомогательного массива с числовым обозначением мест ? И какими методами возможно осуществить замену слов в тексте по ключу и значению ?

Comment: *И как можно реализовать вывод/запись ключей от наибольшего к наименьшему* - отсортируйте stats.items() по кол-ву в порядке убывания, возьмите 10 первых. Про замены ничего не могу посоветовать - не понял

Comment: `print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)[:10])`

Comment: Да насчет, последнего условия согласен, ну я понял, что нужно выполнить замену в строке, которая пойдет в конечный файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `sorted` так, чтобы избежать параметра `reverse`:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x : -x[1])
```